# Avoiding Undefined index in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to avoid undefined index. I have used isset also but i am unable to get the desired results.

```
<body>

    <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "test.php">

<INPUT NAME = "search" size="74">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "SearchButton" VALUE = "Search">
</FORM> 

<?php  
    $search =  isset($_POST['search']);
    //$search = $_POST['search'];
if (!isset($_GET[$search])) {
    // category isn't set
    echo 'not set';

} 
 else {

    echo 'set';
}
?>
```

Comment: $search is a boolean var, as you defined.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? The fact that you are getting a `$_GET` value based on some `$_POST` is confusing. Can you also provide the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
$search =  isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search']  : 'some default';      
$search =  isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search']  : 'some default';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do $_GET[$search], this will either evaluate to $_GET[0] or $_GET[1] depending on whether the parameter 'search' is set as a post variable.
I assume you would need something like

```
if( isset($_POST['search']) ) {
  //do something with the variable
}
```